# cmake 2.8.12 and qt5 error at link

Tags: qt, cmake

I would like to build with cmake (2.8.12) a basic qt5 project generated for testing purpose from qtcreator. The project is just a QApplication that contains a main dialog with a single push button. I followed the instructions given on qt.org and some previous stack 
discussion to finally come up with the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(test WIN32 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Widgets)
```

The build runs fine up to the link stage where I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
```

As far as I understood from qt.org instructions, I do not think 
that I missed any step in setting my cmake file. Would you have any idea of what is wrong with that code ?

EDIT:

Here is finally how Imade my cmake file work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(test)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

qt5_wrap_ui(test_ui mainwindow.ui)

add_executable(test WIN32 main.cpp mainwindow.cpp ${test_ui})
target_link_libraries(test Qt5::Widgets)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the source file for `MainWindow`, likely held in your local file named `MainWindow.cpp`. Did the example use a `QMainWindow`? This was probably missed because now you are using a custom subclass of `QMainWindow`.

Modify the cmake line to:

```
add_executable(test WIN32 main.cpp MainWindow.cpp)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution put me on the right way. However, to make it finally work I had to add modified a bit more my cmake file (cf EDIT)